Primefaces 14 and Java 21, Error in streaming dynamic resource / java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
I'm using @SessionScope from org.springframework.web.context.annotation.SessionScope;
It happens when I download the file using p:fileDownload
<p:column styleClass="w-4rem">
   <h:form>
      <p:commandButton value="Download Form" icon="pi pi-download" styleClass="w-full" actionListener="#{abcHandler.downloadForm}" oncomplete="PF('statusDialog').hide()">
        <f:attribute name="form" value="#{form1}" />
         <p:fileDownload value="#{abcHandler.fileDown}" />
      </p:commandButton>
   </h:form>
</p:column>`

But it doesn't happen all the time, happens once or twice a day. Here's the Java code
public void downloadForm(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        fileDown = null;
        try {
            FormABC form = (FormABC) actionEvent.getComponent().getAttributes().get("form1");
            ABCDocument document = getDocument(form);
            fileDown = DefaultStreamedContent.builder().contentType(document.getFileType().type()).name(document.getFileName())
                    .stream(() -> new ByteArrayInputStream(document.getFileByteArray())).build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (e instanceof InterruptedException)
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            log.error("Exception thrown by downloadForm: ".concat(e.getLocalizedMessage()));
            e.printStackTrace();
            Messages.add(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "There was a problem generating this form " + service.getFormType().toString() + ".", null));
        }
    }

Here's the error stack
java.io.IOException: Error in streaming dynamic resource. Verify you are not using a @ViewScoped bean.
    at org.primefaces.application.resource.StreamedContentHandler.handle(StreamedContentHandler.java:132)
    at org.primefaces.application.resource.PrimeResourceHandler.handleResourceRequest(PrimeResourceHandler.java:89)
    at jakarta.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:166)
    at jakarta.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:166)
    at jakarta.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:166)
    at jakarta.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:166)
    at jakarta.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:166)
    at jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:688)
    at jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:449)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:195)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:14

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:62)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:137)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:102)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:58)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:542)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.flush(SecureNioChannel.java:124)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.write(SecureNioChannel.java:815)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doWrite(NioEndpoint.java:1378)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.doWrite(SocketWrapperBase.java:764)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.writeBlocking(SocketWrapperBase.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.write(SocketWrapperBase.java:533)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:533)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:112)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:193)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:622)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:329)
    ... 67 common frames omitted

Really appreciate every piece of advise on what's going on.
